# Web-scraping множества сайтов

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, web-scraping

Добрый день, немного знаком с парсингом сайтов, но в основном требовалось всегда вытащить данные с 1-2 сайтов для чего использовал python c BeautifulSoup и Requests. Однако столкнулся с задачей, когда есть множество сайтов>20 (причем список может дополняться). У всех сайтов разная разметка естественно, что заводит в тупик. Можете подсказать в какую сторону капать, чтобы вытащить все новости с сайтов?

Comment: Поскольку разметка разная на разных сайтах, то в общем случае невозможно написать парсер, который будет правильно драть нужные вам данные с ЛЮБОГО сайта, который вы парсеру передадите. Также непонятно, что вы подразумеваете под "новостями" - только заголовки? заголовки и основной текст? Может еще и автора в отдельную колонку? Дата и время написания? У меня сейчас одна рекомендация - сузьте проблему и переформулируйте вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел такой вариант, не знаю эффективный он или не очень. 
Словарь {url:ReGex,function} 
url - ccылка на страницу с новостями
ReGex - отбор только интересующих ссылок
function - пишет в файл новость либо скачивает документ.
У меня получилось 50 сайтов, время работы правда большое, поскольку делал тайм-ауты после каждого запроса, чуть меньше 20 минут.